# Access enum entries from anonymous struct

Tags: c++, gcc, struct, enums, enumeration

I've a code like this:

```
struct
{
    enum
    {
        entry,
    } en;

} data;

void foo()
{
    switch(data.en)
    {
    }
}
```

that gives me a warning:

```
main.cpp:13:11: warning: enumeration value 'entry' not handled in switch [-Wswitch]

     switch(data.en)
```

which is expected. I'm curious if I can add `case entry:` without making my struct named one (which obviously works).

This:

```
struct
{
    enum
    {
        entry,
    } en;

} data;

void foo()
{
    switch(data.en)
    {
        case entry:
        break;
    }
}
```

gives an error + warning:

```
main.cpp: In function 'void foo()':

main.cpp:15:14: error: 'entry' was not declared in this scope

         case entry:

              ^~~~~

main.cpp:13:11: warning: enumeration value 'entry' not handled in switch [-Wswitch]

     switch(data.en)

           ^
```

Comment: Is there a question in there? I didn't see it.

Comment: @EOF - _I'm curious if I can add case entry: without making my struct named one_

Comment: The `case entry:` code works for me **when compiling as C rather than C++**.

Comment: @MichałWalenciak you refer to `main.cpp` but the tag is C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C you can do it the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct
{
    enum
    {
        entry,
    } en;

} data = { entry };

void foo()
{
    switch ( data.en )
    {
        case entry:
            puts( "Hello, World!" );
            break;
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    foo();
}
```

In C++ you do it the following way

```
#include <iostream>

struct
{
    enum
    {
        entry,
    } en;

} data = { decltype( data.en )::entry };

void foo()
{
    switch ( data.en )
    {
        case data.entry:
            std::cout <<  "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
            break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

Comment: That's nice. Looks a little bit odd at first glance, but it's quite reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* write:

```
case decltype(data.en)::entry:
```

however I think it would not be considered good code.

Comment: This looks awful :) And a tad funny

Comment: Interesting solution :) Thx